# How do I write a batch script for collecting files with the same name from several directories

Tags: batch-file

I have many files, different, but with the same name, in many directories. These directories are all one level deep within a single root directory.
I would like a script that goes over all these subdirectories, and copies the same-named-files to some destination. Naturally, renaming them.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar requirement recently and I wrote a script to do that. It's not restricted to just files of the same name or a one level deep directory structure, but you can use it for that and I think it should fit your needs. It takes the full filename, strips the current path prefix and converts any backslashes to underscores, thereby "flattening" the directory structure into the filenames. You just need to specify a target directory and a filemask for the script to operate on (lines two and three).

```
@ECHO OFF
SET filemask=*.gif
SET target_path=out
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET current_path=%CD%\
IF NOT EXIST "%target_path%" MKDIR "%target_path%"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /S %filemask%') DO (
    SET file=%%G
    :: strip current path
    SET file_new=!file:%current_path%=!
    :: convert backslashes to underscores
    SET file_new=!file_new:\=_!
    :: copy file
    COPY %%G %target_path%\!file_new! >nul
)
ENDLOCAL
```